# How to combine matrices with sapply in R

Tags: r, matrix, sapply

Each loop of my sapply function will out put a n*m matrix. n is fixed, m is not.
For example, if I run this in R:

```
sapply(1:3, function(x) {matrix(1:9, 3)})
```

and it will output:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    2    2    2
 [3,]    3    3    3
 [4,]    4    4    4
 [5,]    5    5    5
 [6,]    6    6    6
 [7,]    7    7    7
 [8,]    8    8    8
 [9,]    9    9    9
```

However, what I want is something like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    4    7    1    4    7    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8    2    5    8    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9    3    6    9    3    6    9
```

Any idea for this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(1:3, function(x) {matrix(1:9, 3)}))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    4    7    1    4    7    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8    2    5    8    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9    3    6    9    3    6    9
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replicate`

```
`dim<-`(replicate(3, matrix(1:9, 3)), c(3, 3*3))
 #    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 #[1,]    1    4    7    1    4    7    1    4    7
 #[2,]    2    5    8    2    5    8    2    5    8
 #[3,]    3    6    9    3    6    9    3    6    9
```